# After re-starting device my locker application is not working on the Android marshmallow device

Tags: android, android-service, sharedpreferences, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-broadcastreceiver

I am working on App locker application. If installed this
    application in kitkat version device application locking and its
    working perfect. In marshmallow|(6.0) version device initially
    application is working, if we restart the device app lock is not
    working, Locked applications are open without asking any password.
    If we just enter application (app Lock app) and exit from app its
    working perfect. That time it asks password.

```
public class StartupServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
        if (AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isAutoStart()){
            if (AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isServiceEnabled()){
                context.startService(new Intent(context, DetectorService.class));
            }else{
                AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).saveServiceEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        return;
    }else if (AppLockerPreference.getInstance(context).isServiceEnabled()){
        context.startService(new Intent(context, DetectorService.class));
    }
}
}


public class AppLockerPreference implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
Context mContext;




public boolean isAutoStart() {
    Log.d("AMK","AppLockerPreference1--->"+mApplicationList.length);
    return mAutoStart;
}

public boolean isServiceEnabled() {
    Log.d("AMK","AppLockerPreference2--->"+mApplicationList.length);
    return mServiceEnabled;
}
public void saveServiceEnabled(boolean serviceEnabled) {
    mServiceEnabled = serviceEnabled;
    mPref.edit().putBoolean(PREF_SERVICE_ENABLED, mServiceEnabled);
}
public String[] getApplicationList() {


    Log.d("AMK","AppLockerPreference3--->"+mApplicationList.length);
    return mApplicationList;
}
public void saveApplicationList(String[] applicationList) {
    mApplicationList = applicationList;
    String combined = "";
    for (int i=0; i<mApplicationList.length; i++){
        combined = combined + mApplicationList[i] + ";";
    }
    mPref.edit().putString(PREF_APPLICATION_LIST, combined).commit();
}

private static final String PREF_SERVICE_ENABLED = "service_enabled";
private static final String PREF_APPLICATION_LIST = "application_list";
private static final String PREF_AUTO_START = "start_service_after_boot";
private static final String PREF_PASSWORD = "password";

/**
 * Section for singleton pattern
 */
private SharedPreferences mPref;
private AppLockerPreference(Context context) {
    mPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    mPref.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    reloadPreferences();
}
private void reloadPreferences() {
    mServiceEnabled = mPref.getBoolean(PREF_SERVICE_ENABLED, true);

    mApplicationList = mPref.getString(PREF_APPLICATION_LIST, "").split(";");



    Log.d("AMK","selectd apps--->"+mApplicationList);



    mAutoStart = mPref.getBoolean(PREF_AUTO_START, true);
    mPassword = mPref.getString(PREF_PASSWORD, "2468");
    if (mPref.getBoolean("relock_policy", true)){
        try{
            mRelockTimeout = Integer.parseInt(mPref.getString("relock_timeout", "-1"));
        }catch(Exception e){
            mRelockTimeout = -1;
        }
    }else{
        mRelockTimeout = -1;
    }
}

private static AppLockerPreference mInstance;
public static AppLockerPreference getInstance(Context context){
    return mInstance == null ?
            (mInstance = new AppLockerPreference(context)) :
                mInstance;
}

private boolean mServiceEnabled, mAutoStart;
private String[] mApplicationList;
private String mPassword;
private int mRelockTimeout;

public int getRelockTimeout(){
    return mRelockTimeout;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return mPassword;
}
public void savePassword(String password) {
    mPassword = password;
    mPref.edit().putString(PREF_PASSWORD, password);
}

public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,
        String key) {
    reloadPreferences();
}
}
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: You DO have ``<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
`` in your manifest file?

Comment: Yes.I have this permission.

Comment: give us your manifest

Answer (score 0):

check if the device is marshmallow and give permissions

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.MARSHMALLOW) {
     // only for marshmallow and newer versions
}
```

Comment: Not working...After restarting device getting locked application length.               If we just enter application (app Lock app) and exit from app its working perfect. That time it asks password.